# Получение свойств наследников при обходе коллекции объектов циклом

Tags: java

У меня есть некий набор объектов:

```
List<UserType> userTypes = сonfiguration.getUserTypes();
```

Если я обхожу его в цикле:

```
for (SmbpUserType userType : userTypes) {
            // do smth
}
```

Из объекта `userType` я могу вытащить свойства соответственно только класса `UserType`, но в этом листе также лежат и наследники `UserType`. Получается к ним никаким образом доступ не получить?

Comment: Как вариант -- можно скастить суперкласс к сабклассу (если он таковым является). Но это плохо.

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать внутри цикла?

Comment: @JVic, делать запись в БД. Но в зависимости от объекта и его данных, это будет запись в разные таблицы.

Comment: Определите в суперклассе метод, который бы формировал данные для сохранения в БД. А в наследниках - переопределяйте по необходимости. В цикле вызывайте этот метод и будете получать данные в зависимости от конкретного типа.

Comment: @Nikolay, не совсем понимаю, как он должен "формировать данные"?  Этот класс и его наследники это обычные `POJO`.

Comment: Добавьте пример в цикле - как вы сохраняете данные.

Comment: @Nikolay, я пока думаю как это делать. Лучшее что пришло в голову, в цикле делать instanceof и cast'овать к соответствующему типу и потом уже через `jdbctemplate` сохранять в базу

Comment: Если использовать jdbctemplate, то так и придется делать - проверять тип, формировать запрос и пр. Как вариант - использовать ORM, или отдельно EntityManager, который бы делал все это за вас.

Comment: @Nikolay, а с использованием дженериков это никак не сделать?

Comment: логику сохранения объектов в БД лучше вынести в отдельный слой (DAO), затем вы можете зарегистрировать все DAO в одном месте и связать тип объекта с его DAO. И затем в цикле получать нужный DAO и передавать внутрь объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации в дополнение к комментарию.

```
public class Example {

    public static abstract class UserType {}
    public static class AUser extends UserType {}
    public static class BUser extends UserType {}

    public interface DAO<T extends UserType> {
        void save(T entity);
    }

    public static class UserTypeDAO implements DAO<UserType> {
        private static final DAOProvider DAO_PROVIDER = new DAOProvider();
        @Override
        public void save(UserType entity) {
            DAO dao = DAO_PROVIDER.getDAO(entity.getClass());
            if (dao == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("DAO for class %s is not registered", entity.getClass()));
            }
            dao.save(entity);
        }
    }

    public static class AUserDAO implements DAO<AUser> {
        @Override
        public void save(AUser entity) {
            System.out.println("save AUser");
        }
    }

    public static class BUserDAO implements DAO<BUser> {
        @Override
        public void save(BUser entity) {
            System.out.println("save BUser");
        }
    }

    public static class DAOProvider {
        private static final Map<Class<? extends UserType>, DAO<? extends UserType>> daos = new HashMap<>();
        static {
            daos.put(AUser.class, new AUserDAO());
            daos.put(BUser.class, new BUserDAO());
        }

        public <T extends UserType> DAO<T> getDAO(Class<T> clz) {
            return (DAO<T>) daos.get(clz);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...args){
        UserTypeDAO dao = new UserTypeDAO();

        UserType a = new AUser();
        UserType b = new BUser();

        dao.save(a);
        dao.save(b);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Агрегация наследников полезна, только когда при их обходе вы хотите обращаться к методам, заявленным в их общем интерфейсе или классе-родителе.

Есть несколько простых альтернатив:

1. Если задача не подразумевает дальнейшее добавление новых подтипов, то можно разделить данную коллекцию на несколько (по типам);
2. Если в дальнейшем будут добавляться новые подтипы, но вы хотите работать с ними так же единообразно, то следует вынести необходимые методы в класс-предок или интерфейс и переопределять их в наследниках.

Но я бы предпочел завести интерфейс с методами, которые необходимы данному циклу обработки и имплементировал его всеми использумыми классами.

Пример:

```
public interface Speaking {

    String sayHello();
}

public class Human implements Speaking {

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Agu";
    }
}

public class Homosapiens extends Human {

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public String think() {
        return "I think - then I exist";
    }
}

public class Driopithecus extends Human {

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Arar!";
    }

    public void crush() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Speaking> speakings = new ArrayList<>();
        speakings.add(new Human());
        speakings.add(new Homosapiens());
        speakings.add(new Driopithecus());

        for (Speaking speaking : speakings) {
            System.out.println(speaking.sayHello());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нормальный Java подход заключается в том, чтобы наследники `UserType` реализовывали методы сохранения в своей локальной инкарнации.

Самоделки, а ля `instanceof` или ручного кастинга - это не из серии ООП.

```
abstract class UserType {
   public abstract void save();
}

class UserTypeA extends UserType {
   public void save() {
      // do smth
   }
}

class UserTypeB extends UserType {
   public void save() {
      // do smth
   }
}
```

Можно сделать `UserType` в виде `interface` - как показывает ответ @Nikolay

Comment: Выполнение сохранения внутри класса - плохая идея. Этим должен заниматься слой работы с данными.

Comment: Плохая идея пытаться везде и всегда проталкивать шаблон *multi-tier*, у каждого шаблона есть своя область применения, так что не надо пороть горячку. К тому же предлагаемый подход никак не отменяет любимую вашу *слоистость*, вполне можно "посадить" внутри `save()` вызов слоя работы с данными :)

Comment: Дело не в "любимой" слоистости. UserType и его наследники - это обычные POJO объекты для хранения атрибутов и они не должны знать ничего о других уровнях абстракций, вносить в них работу с БД - неверно (нарушение принципов SOLID и т.д.).

Comment: Отставим дискуссию, за очевидной холиварностью темы, тем более, что я уже ответил в предыдущем комментарии. Отмечу лишь, что советую вам не увлекаться сильно модными терминами :)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я, пожалуй, все таки буду "увлекаться модными терминами", к тому же упомянутый мною SOLID определяет основные принципы ООП, и их знание я считаю важным. А дискуссию и, правда, стоит завершить.